# Visual Studio Command 'Python' Select Interpreter resulted in an error. Command 'python.setInterpreter not found'

Tags: python, opencv, visual-studio-code, anaconda3

I downloaded the Python extension in Visual Studio Code and set the Conda Path to the python.exe under Anaconda3. Additionally, I set the default interpreter path to 'python.exe' located at 'users\appdata\local\programs\python312'. However, I'm still encountering the error mentioned in the question.

I'm trying to set up the interpreter.

Comment: What's the version of your python extension and VSCode? Could you please try to use pre-release version of python extenion?